# AEM OTB i18n translation works even when no translation strings available

Tags: internationalization, aem

It was strange when I found i18n labels from otb dictionaries work even when the translation strings are not present. For example the dialog string 'Advanced'
[image]

doesnt show any translation. But am able to see properly translated strings on dialog like this
[image]

How does OTB do this?

Comment: most probably that translation is available in multiple dictionaries.

Comment: No I checked all otb dictionaries. Present in only one and that too seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had included only en_Ca and fr_Ca locales under /etc/languages. Adding en, fr languages also to /etc/languages is showing the translated content. It is available otb, only I was not picking the right language.